# No device yet in pushbots

Tags: push-notification, server-push, pushapps

I am new to pushbots and have done push notification as it given in tutorial, but when I click on Dashboard and then push it display an alert box which messaged "No devices Yet" I am not getting how to add device while I have installed apps in Android mobile. 
Please help me out...

Comment: I have the same problem in iOS, i followed all the steps of the dev center and I still have no device

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and made sure more than once that everything is right
Then tried to uninstall the app and install it again with taking instance from MyApplication in my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new MyApplication();

    }
}
```

And This worked for me, but when i tried again to delete the instance and delete uninstall the app it still registered on pushbots website!!